# How to make a package play well with others?

Tags: macros, naming

I have an ever growing preamble and it contains commands like `\su` and `\so` for the **s**pecial **u**nitary and **s**pecial **o**rthogonal group algebra, just `\mathfrak{SU}`. Then later I wanted to use the `soul` package to strike out some text. Its command is `\so` for **s**trike**o**ut. Both abbreviations do make sense and when I tried lo load `soul`, I got an error, of course.

In programming languages there are often namespaces (Python, C++) but then my commands would have to be much longer and would be a pain to type.

Is there any other way to prevent this beforehand?  Or is that a fundamendal difficulty with LaTeX?

Comment: That is not a LaTeX problem. You can put a label called *egg* on an *apple* and similar label on a *peach*. Now, it either is random, the last tagged item or the warning/error that you cannot label different things with the same tag. Or define the same command twice.

Comment: The usual problem is 'lazyness' -- We don't want to type long commands, but most package commands are short in name, the likelihood to have a name clash is quite large, especially for compounds like `strike-out`. Even if it is annoying or tedious: Use longer names for your 'abbrevations'

Comment: Or at least, use particular wordings: if `\su` exists, then change it to `\mysu`. Usually adding **my** helps. For example, `\circ` is an existing command, but `\mycirc` is fair territory.

Comment: @Alenanno **my** is an often used but fairly strange prefix i think. It is the same for your documents, as well as for mine, because the def is ours. How about using the name initials? Like `JB` for my name or `LT` as used with longtable.

Comment: @Johannes_B Well, either is fine, as long as you are reasonably sure that it's not going to break anything. Initials are not always a sure choice, because your initials might be coincidentally be the same of a command/package. :D

Answer (score 13):

For internal package names many packages have a pseudo namespacing scheme of prefixing commands with a (hopefully) unique prefix, so `longtable` internals are all `\LT@...`, `tabularx` internals are all `\TX@...`

For packages using `expl3` conventions the internal prefixing is more formalised and there is a register of prefix names to avoid clashes.

https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/l3kernel/l3prefixes.csv

At the top level you could do that (without the non-letter-separator) so
for example `longtable` has some lengths starting `\LT`  without an `@` 
`\LTpre` but mostly you just don't do that and "grab" some usefully short name.

There are usually fewer top level commands and it is easier to alias them:
if two packages define `\foo` it is often (not always:-) enough to use something like

```
\usepackage{pkga}
\let\fooa\foo
\let\foo\undefined
\usepackage{pkgb}
\let\foob\foo
```

So that you have both functionalities available but under the names `\fooa` and `\foob`.

Again the programming model underlying `expl3` tries to formalise this, the idea is that you have your functionality written using prefixed names and `expl3` syntax conventions but then one or more top level user interface commands can be defined using `xparse` that call the underlying code, so if you need a different name you should at most have to change the `xparse` declaration, all the main functionality should be in uniquely prefixed package code.

Comment: Perhaps also note that in a single document it would be tricky (at least) to use `\foo` for two different meanings other than within rather restricted contexts (_e.g._ in `siunitx` I use `\pm` for 'picometre' in units).